# Sybase IQ Transaction Status

Tags: transactions, sap-iq

We are running Sybase IQ V 15.4.
We often see transactions that are shown in sp_iqtransactions as COMMITTED for a long time before being APPLIED.
I'm trying to find an explanation of what is happening in the database to a transaction during this time, between being COMMITTED and APPLIED.

Thanks